# text height is inconsistent across pages

Tags: fancyhdr, geometry

I am trying to typeset a document where the page numbers are flush with the bottom of the text. I discovered, however, that not every block of text has the same height. The presence of sectioning commands, etc. slightly changes the text height.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,footskip=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext,fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize\itshape \thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\section{a section}
\subsection{a subsection}
\blindtext[12]
\end{document}
```

The second page has more space at the bottom, so the difference in space between the page number and text in the first and second pages is quite noticeable when you remove `showframe`.

This may just be a feature of TeX's paragraph building or line breaking algorithm that I have to live with. Is this the case, or is there a way to force the heights to be the same?

Comment: This is a feature of the design of the document class, in particular the size and vertical spacing associated with section headings and similar.  Unless the document class is designed to rigidly conform to a grid, if a page contains only one paragraph, and the length doesn't take into consideration that there's one less increment of leading than the number of lines on the page, there's no ability to adjust spacing at paragraph breaks to exactly meet the specified page length.  Don't blame TeX.  The same thing would happen with hand-set type.

Comment: @barbarabeeton No blame here. Though with hand-set type, I'd imagine you could manually adjust the spacing between page number and text so that it's the same for each page

Comment: `\flushbottom` ?

Comment: You are warned you are specifying unachievable page geometry: Package fancyhdr Warning: \footskip is too small (0.0pt): 
(fancyhdr)                Make it at least 10.25pt, for example:
(fancyhdr)                \setlength{\footskip}{10.25pt}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

`fancyheader` warns you

```
Package fancyhdr Warning: \footskip is too small (0.0pt): 
(fancyhdr)                Make it at least 10.25pt, for example:
(fancyhdr)                \setlength{\footskip}{10.25pt}.
```

But here I think you want it `\baselineskip` (12pt)

also then added `heightrounded` `geometry` option to avoid

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [2]
```

and finally add `\flushbottom` so the section space stretches to bring the last line of page 1 to the bottom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,footskip=12pt,includefoot,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext,fancyhdr}
\flushbottom
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize\itshape \thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\section{a section}
\subsection{a subsection}
\blindtext[12]
\end{document}
```